# Hide object's field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

I defined a blueprint for a simple stopwatch object with this function constructor:

```
function StopWatch() {
    function now() {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getTime();
    }
    this.start = now();
    this.elapsed = function() {
        return Math.round((now() - this.start) / 1000);
    }
}
```

I can now save the reference to a new stopwatch in `s`:

```
var s = new Stopwatch();
```

And obtain the time elapsed in seconds:

```
s.elapsed();
```

But the `start` property is also accessible. How can I hide it?

Comment: Declare it as a local variable, with `var`, not `this`.

Comment: I recommend [this site](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) for a very nice coverage of Javascript coding patterns. (No, I am not affiliated with it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the `start` property in the object being constructed, by doing

```
this.start = now();
```

Instead, you can simply declare the variable locally and it will still be available to the `elapsed` function, because of the closure property.

```
function StopWatch() {
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();

    this.elapsed = function() {
        return Math.round(((new Date()).getTime() - start) / 1000);
    }
}
```

Or, you can return an object from the function, like this

```
function StopWatch() {
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();

    return {
        elapsed: function() {
            return Math.round(((new Date()).getTime() - start) / 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel a bit silly, so simple. Now let me understand this bit conceptually if I can: when you say the local variable is _available_ to the `elapsed` method, do you mean: a) that when the method of an already constructed object is called, the reference of the local `start` is searched for or: b) is the reference written into the method at the time of the object's creation?

Comment: @BoLe When the `elapsed` function is created, there will be a variable called `start` in its scope and it will retain the value between multiple calls. So, you can treat that like a private variable.

Comment: Also, if I may: Is it advisable to create an object with `new` call to a function constructor or use an ordinary function which returns an object {}-structure as in your second example?

Comment: @BoLe When you use `new` operator, a new object will be created and that will be set as the `this` special variable, so that you can customize it in the constructor function. Even if you don't return anything explicitly from a constructor function, the `this` object will be returned by default, when you use `new` operator. But, if you explicitly return an Object, then JavaScript will not return `this` but your object. So, both are acceptable.